# Highlight negative numbers in red

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table gathering data from mysql. I use jquery to highlight the negative data in red.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('td').each(function() {                                 
    var cellvalue = $(this).html();
    if ( cellvalue.substring(0,1) == '-' ) {
         $(this).wrapInner('<strong class="colorred"></strong>');   
    }
   });                     
});
```

It works, but only in the last column, and i cant figure out why!!

any ideas?

here's the jsFiddle link
http://jsfiddle.net/atseros/Af6Nz/17/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `trim()` as you have unnecessary space in your `td` -

```
 var cellvalue = $.trim($(this).html());
```

Demo `---->` http://jsfiddle.net/Af6Nz/20/

Comment: Better to use `$.trim($(this).html())` as  `.trim()` will throw an error in IE8

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use `if ( cellvalue < 0) {`

```
$('td').each(function() {
    var cellvalue = $(this).html();
    if ( cellvalue < 0) {
        $(this).wrapInner('<strong class="colorred"></strong>');    
    }
});
```

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Af6Nz/19/)